# How to get the response from external web browser into .net winforms WebBrowser?

Tags: vb.net, powerbi

I have a webbrowser control in my applications that loads a power bi report that needs users to sign in to be able to see the report inside the browser. The issue is that when user clicks on the sign in button, it    opens a new internet explorer window to login and when log in is done, nothing happens in the web browser inside the application. How can I get the response back from login window?

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    WebBrowser1.Navigate(BIReport)
End Sub
```

BIReport is the link to the power BI report generated from power BI Service.

Comment: See the [Navigate(Uri, String, Byte(), String)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.navigate) overload: pass "_self" as the second argument, then `null` (`Nothing`) and additional headers, if required (that last string argument can represent a `User-Agent:` header, in case you want to *impersonate* a different Browser - it's sometimes required for compatibility reasons).

Comment: It will not work with IE. Better use [`CefSharp`](https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp) instead of `WebBrowser`. You can download a functional demo app in c# from [here](https://www.sqlsaturday.com/878/Sessions/Details/sid/90151) (which also shows how it doesn't work with WebBrowser and IE).